# Is it correct to use Exclamation mark(!) in the introduction of a Professional Email?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, formality, politeness

I work with teams that are in different geographic zones. This is how I usually, start the email introduction. for example:-

```
Hi Linda,

Good Morning! or Greetings!
```

Is it correct to use exclamation mark in the phrase. Is it polite or professional?

Comment: It's "friendly".  Only you can decide what degree of friendliness is appropriate.

Comment: It might be polite or friendly, but it doesn't look professional at all. This is a "primarily opinion-based" comment.

Comment: I think it is more common in some other languages. ...

Comment: I use exclamation points a lot in my e-mail correspondence! But doing so mainly indicates a heightened level of real or simulated enthusiasm on my part! Ultimately, I'm not at all sure it does much for the image of professionalism I'm trying to cultivate! But on the other hand, I don't see how it could be taken as impolite!

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience it's improper to use "!" in any sort of formal email.